# Does coolant have a shelf life?

Tags: coolant, cooling-system

I have found some old opened bottles of coolant (green, undiluted, aluminum safe) in my garage, they've been opened and partially used.  The remaining coolant has been there for somewhere between 5 and 10 years.  Is it still ok to use, or should I throw it out and buy a new bottle?  Do the corrosion inhibitors become less effective when stored this way?

Comment: have a look at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/11972/10976